# Tips for pronouncing sounds that does not exist in the student's mother thongue

Tags: phonetics, phonology, phonemes

This is my first post here.
My name is Bruno and I'm a native (Brazilian) Portuguese speaker.
Besides Portuguese, I only have a rough knowledge of American English.

I spite of that, I am trying to learn something of another languages,
but one of the most difficult things for me is how to pronounce
sounds that don't exist in Portuguese. In my opinion , this is even
more difficult than learning to read/write and recognize characters
other than the familiar 'a'-to-'z' letters (e.g. Russian, Greek or
even Georgian).

I will use Finnish as an example, because it is a language that
sounds and looks (with all those double vowels) alien to me,
and that have an interesting phonology as well: a rather small
number of vowels and consonants but many of them nonexistent
in my mother language.

Please, excuse me if I use 'phonology' and other linguistic jargon
wrongly - I'm no linguist.

Back to Finnish, I learned that it has both a near open front
unrounded vowel [æ] and a (near)open back [ɑ] vowel.
Portuguese has an [a] that is open front (or central).

The problem is how to learn to spell those vowels.
I try the following (e.g. for [æ]):

1  I begin speaking eeeee... ([ɛ],open mid) gradually changing,
without interruption, to aaaaa... ([a],open front) and at the same
time trying to identify and further repeat the sound in between.

2  To pronounce ea [ɛa] in a fast way trying to merge the e and
the a in one sound.

3  Trying to imitate foreign words that contains this sound
after hearing a native speaker spelling it.
This is the obvious way but is not always easy because for
certain languages it is difficult to find even recorded
materials let alone a native speaker (and I am an introvert).

4  Reading about how these sounds are pronounced, trying
to comprehend how the sounds in the IPA chart are produced,
etc.

Sometimes I can pronounce what I think is the correct sound,
but how to do it fast, in the same effortless, relaxed way
a native speaker do? After enough time and practice just 
like anything one want to master, I suppose.

Finally, the question is: do you have another tips and
suggestions to share? comments anyone?

Comment: Requests for language-learning tips are kind of off-topic here. My suggestion is that you try to reconceptualize this into a scientific question with a correct answer, such as "how do children learn to produce the sounds of their native language?"